# Can I use Pardot Integration to custom operations?

Tags: integration, pardot

My org is synchronized with Pardot. All operations use different endpoints than those indicated in the official API documentation. For example, to read the lists, this call is made:

https://embedded.demo.pardot.com/prospect/getLists

while in the official documentation this is indicated:

https://pi.demo.pardot.com/api/list/version/4/do/query

Can I therefore take advantage of the integration to be able to make custom calls?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.pardot.com/ the main URL for API requests is https://pi.pardot.com/api.

Currently, embedded.demo.pardot.com is a DNS CNAME pointer to pi.demo.pardot.com.

Both of the URLs you posted suggested your Pardot instance is actually a demo instance and NOT a Production instance. You might want to work with your Salesforce Support contact OR your Systems Integrator (Pardot Consultant?) to look into that for you.